# Can I use Bulb exposure with wireless shutter release?

Tags: wireless, remote, shutter-release

Curious if I can use Bulb exposure with a wireless remote on the Rebel series bodies from Canon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, provided that your Rebel supports remote shutter release.

Just different remotes will behave differently and you need to check how exactly. Some will open the shutter on first push of the button and close on the second, while the others need to be held down during the whole exposure time. This behavior might also depend on other settings, like mirror-lockup (if I remember it correctly I was only able to get the former behavior when ML was *disabled* with my 5D and cheap Yongnuo remote, because when I was using ML the first push actuated ML and the second push+hold was for exposure). If you do really long exposures, the two-click approach where you don't have to hold the trigger is preferred.

Comment: Press ounce for open, press again for close worked.  Thanks!